# Filter JSON data based on certain properties and values

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have the following JSON object:

```
{
  'name' : 'John',
  'friends' : [
    {
      'id' : 1,
      'name' : 'George',
      'level' : 10
    },
    {
      'id' : 2,
      'name' : 'Stacy',
      'level' : 8
    },
    {
      'id' : 3,
      'name' : 'Fred',
      'level' : 10
    },
    {
      'id' : 4,
      'name' : 'Amy',
      'level' : 7
    },
    {
      'id' : 5,
      'name' : 'Bob',
      'level' : 10
    }
  ]
}
```

So as you can see, you have an object (person?) that has a `name`, and an array of `friend` objects. Each friend object has an `id`, `name` and `level`.

What I'd like to do, is select all the level 10 friends out of that array, and into another variable/object called `var level10Friends`.

I'm using AngularJS and all this needs to happen in my controller, but this doesn't necessarily have to be an AngularJS specific problem, you're welcome to use vanilla JavaScript functions as well.

To be honest I don't even know if this is possible and searching the web doesn't seem to bring anything up about something like this...

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Or expecting someone to do this for you ?

Comment: That's very observable of you. But if I don't even know if this is possible, and you've searched for well over an hour on the web, where do you even start? Might be worth mentioning that I'm looking for a vanilla JavaScript or Angular way of doing this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). *The `filter()` method creates a new `array` with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.*

```js
var users = {
  'name': 'John',
  'friends': [{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'George',
    'level': 10
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Stacy',
    'level': 8
  }, {
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'Fred',
    'level': 10
  }, {
    'id': 4,
    'name': 'Amy',
    'level': 7
  }, {
    'id': 5,
    'name': 'Bob',
    'level': 10
  }]
};
var wantedData = users.friends.filter(function(i) {
  return i.level === 10;
});
console.log(wantedData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var level10friends = list.friends.filter(function(p){return p.level == 10;});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using arrow functions you can do it as:

```
var filteredFriends = list.friends.filter( p => p.level === 10 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found this plugin this morning
http://linqjs.codeplex.com/

Its a way to query JSON using linq function.
I LOVE IT ^^

EDIT:

little example for your case:

```
var jsonArray = {your-json-array}
var level10Friends = Enumerable.From(jsonArray)
    .Where("$.user.level == 10")
    .Select("$.user.name")
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look!

```js
angular
  .module('test', [])
  .value('user', {
  'name' : 'John',
  'friends' : [{
      'id' : 1,
      'name' : 'George',
      'level' : 10
    },
    {
      'id' : 2,
      'name' : 'Stacy',
      'level' : 8
    },
    {
      'id' : 3,
      'name' : 'Fred',
      'level' : 10
    },
    {
      'id' : 4,
      'name' : 'Amy',
      'level' : 7
    },
    {
      'id' : 5,
      'name' : 'Bob',
      'level' : 10
    }]
  })
  .controller('TestCtrl', function TestCtrl($scope, user) {
    var vm = $scope;
    vm.level10friends = (function(friends, REQUIRED_LEVEL) {
      var res = [];
      
      for(var friend, i = 0, len = friends.length; i < len; i++) {
        friend = friends[i];
        
        if(friend.level === REQUIRED_LEVEL) {
          res.push(friend);
        }
        
      }
      
      return res;
    }).call(this, user.friends || [], 10);
  })
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<article ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <div ng-bind="level10friends | json"></div>
  </div>  
</article>
```